# Windows Phone 8 Panorama Binding Bug?

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8, binding

I've come across an issue with the Panorama Control on Windows Phone 8.
Created a project to test the issue using simple code based on the WP Panorama Project template.
So I'm binding to an Observable Collection using INotifyPropertyChanged interface (MVVM).

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage

<!  ...  >

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

     <!--Panorama control-->
    <phone:Panorama ItemsSource="{Binding PageTitles}"
                    Title="Panorama Test">
        <phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="410" Margin="-2,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock d:DataContext="{Binding}" Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource PanoramaItemHeaderTextStyle}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
        <phone:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets\PanoramaBackground.png"/>
        </phone:Panorama.Background>

        <phone:PanoramaItem Name="Screen1">
            <Grid Margin="0,-6,0,12">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="420" Height="500" BorderBrush="#FFFFC700" Background="#FFFFC700"/>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>            
        <phone:PanoramaItem Name="Screen2">
            <Grid Margin="0,-6,0,12">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="420" Height="500" BorderBrush="#FFFFC700" Background="#FFFFC700"/>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>            
        <phone:PanoramaItem Name="Screen3">
            <Grid Margin="0,-6,0,12">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="420" Height="500" BorderBrush="#FFFFC700" Background="#FFFFC700"/>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
        <phone:PanoramaItem Name="Screen4" >
            <Grid Margin="0,-6,0,12">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="420" Height="500" BorderBrush="#FFFFC700" Background="#FFFFC700"/>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

When in the Visual Studio 2013 Design View, in place of the page content I see I single line that reads:

_.di28.Induction.Viewmodels.ItemViewModel

and when run in the Emulator, it reads:

Induction.Viewmodels.ItemViewModel

I've restructured the Binding in all the ways I can think of and find, but the problem remains.
Is this a bug with the Panorama Control under Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will resolve your issue but you're misunderstanding something :
The ItemsSource property is not only there for the titles but for the whole PanoramaItems collection.
You should not redefine every PanoramaItem after that but use a datatemplate instead :  just like for the HeaderTemplate :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

 <!--Panorama control-->
<phone:Panorama ItemsSource="{Binding PageTitles}"
                Title="Panorama Test">
    <phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="410" Margin="-2,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock d:DataContext="{Binding}" Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource PanoramaItemHeaderTextStyle}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
    <phone:Panorama.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets\PanoramaBackground.png"/>
    </phone:Panorama.Background>
    <phone:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <phone:PanoramaItem>
                <Grid Margin="0,-6,0,12">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="420" Height="500" BorderBrush="#FFFFC700" Background="#FFFFC700"/>
                </Grid>
            </phone:PanoramaItem>   
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
</phone:Panorama>
```

I cannot test right now but at least you get the idea. Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I tried it and it only partially works, as the code runs in the emulator but causes Visual Studio 2013 Design screen to crash with a NullReferenceException.
In any case, what if I want each PanoramaItem to have different content?

Comment: There are two options : If you know exactly what you want to show, then you should not go with the Templates approach and just define each of you PanoramaItems, including their headers in xaml. On the contrary, if you want to be able to add PanoramaItems dynamicaly, you should turn your PageTitle into a bigger object that would contain not only the PanoramaItem Header, but other properties such as it's background, content, etc... Is there a reason why you're trying to bind the Panorama ItemsSource instead of directly defining each PanoramaItem in xaml ?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use a single MVVM data source to populate the PanoramaItem Header (Title) and use the same data for a LongListSelector as a Menu placed as the right-most page of the Panorama.  The LongListSelector Items would use the Image-Filename <Button>, Title <TextBlock> and Help-Text <TextBlock> from the MVVM data source in a DataTemplate.